# Dealing with absolute paths while on localhost

Tags: 7, uri

I have a long-term path problem while developing modules.

For instance I have the following project path http://localhost:8888/mylocalproject, which (on the production server) would be http://www.project.com.

Now each time I use global $base_url or other absolute paths it only returns me the http://localhost:8888/ not http://localhost:8888/mylocalproject. For instance if I want to handcraft a logout link will give me http://localhost:8888/user/logout which is wrong, since mylocalproject is excluded.

I have all the time to hack solutions like this

```
global $base_url;
$needle = "localhost";
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $needle)) {
  path = $base_url."/mylocalproject";
}
else {
  path = $base_url;
}
```

Is there a Drupal standard solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just set the `$base_url` in your settings file while you're working on localhost, then you can just change it when you put the site live.

The settings file is at "sites/default/settings.php" and you should add:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8888/mylocalproject';
```

Obviously when the site goes live you want to change/remove that line to match your new environment.

Comment: or better ?   global $base_url;
  
  $needle = "localhost";
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $needle)) {
   //$path = $base_url."/psaldo";
   $path = 'http://localhost:8888/psaldo';
}
else {
 $path = $base_url;
}

Comment: actually, this didn't work for me. I cleared the cache. links to "/" are still going to localhost:8888. Anything else I need to change? Thanks

Comment: @MotoTribe If your links are hard coded as "/" then that's how they'll stay, the `$base_url` is used by internal functions to construct URLs, it doesn't do any sort of replacement on hard-coded URLs used in templates/content/etc. If you're hard coding links and want to use `$base_url` they would look like this: `$link = $base_url . '/a-link.html'`. Even better though, use the `l()` or `url()` functions as @MPD has suggested as this will take care of everything for you

Comment: oic. Thanks. Looks like I'm back to configuring MAMP for each site

Comment: If you can get a copy of MAMP pro you can have as many sites (virtual hosts) as you want with hostnames like "http://mysite.local". It works a treat for me

Comment: @MotoTribe look on my first comment: use strpos php function to detect the word localhost in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and if there is, alter the path variable.

Comment: thanks again. Got it working now by including the $base_url in my absolute links. I'll switch to MAMP pro - after I launched my site ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should really use [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) and [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) as much as humanly possible.  If you look at the source, you will see the use of [base_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7) to tack on the proper prefix for where you have Drupal installed.  This does assume you have `$basepath` set properly, which should include the sub-directory (as needed) and not just the hostname/portnumber.  A bonus with this is that it takes aliases into account, do you don't need to do gloabl search/replace in code when you change the URL for something.

EDIT TO ADDRESS COMMENT:

```
$link = l("Add Content", "node/add", array("attributes" => array("class" => "shlinks")));
$shortcut_set['my_list'][] = array("#markup" => "<li>" . $link . "</li>");
```